# Using Videos in Gatsby Markdown

Tags: typescript, video, markdown, gatsby

I am building my portfolio page on Gatsby 3.10.1 want to use video loops on my portfolio frontpage for each blog-post, which start and stop when hovering over it. I attached a `videoThumbnail` value to each blogpost in the frontmatter and used the code below for the frontpage. For the eventHandling i mostly followed this instruction: [Creating a Video Thumbnail Previews in GatsbyJS](https://cloudinary.com/blog/guest_post/creating-a-video-thumbnail-previews-in-gatsbyjs)

It seems like in theory the code works, but the video files are not built into the development or production builds, thus the video elements stay empty. When I add them to the production build manually it works, but I don't want to do it manually each time I update the site, and previewing the build in development is not possible.

What do I have to do to make the files appear in the builds?

postCard.js, which creates the overview of all posts on my frontpage:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

  // handle mouse enter
  const handleMouseEnter = (e) => {
    const vid = e.target
    vid.play()
  }
  // handle mouse leave
  const handleMouseLeave = (e) => {
    const vid = e.target
    vid.currentTime = 0
    vid.pause()
  }

const postcard = props => (
  <article
    className={`post-card-2 ${props.postClass} ${props.node.frontmatter.thumbnail ? `with-image` : `no-image`}`}
    
  >
    <Link to={props.node.fields.slug} className="post-card-link post-card-content">
        <h2 className="post-card-title">{props.node.frontmatter.title}</h2>
        {props.node.frontmatter.videoThumbnail &&
        <video className="post-card-thumbnail" loop muted onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} onTouchStart={handleMouseEnter} onTouchEnd={handleMouseLeave}>
          <source
            src={props.node.frontmatter.videoThumbnail.relativePath}
            type="video/mp4"
          />
        </video>}
      {props.node.frontmatter.thumbnail && 
      <GatsbyImage
            className="post-card-thumbnail"
            image={props.node.frontmatter.thumbnail.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData}
            alt={props.node.frontmatter.title}
            objectFit="cover"
            />}
       
    </Link>
  </article>
)
export default postcard;
```

a frontmatter example:

```
---
title: Illusion Of Seclusion
date: "2019-05-11"
videoThumbnail: ./illusionofseclusion.mp4
thumbnail: ./illusionofseclusion.jpg
description: Tanzmusikvideo zur Musik von Photay
videoSourceURL: "https://player.vimeo.com/video/417153063"
---
```

The element in the index page:

```
<PostCard
              key={node.fields.slug}
              count={postCounter}
              node={node}
              postClass={`post`}
              videoThumbnail={node.frontmatter.videoThumbnail}
            />
```

there is also a graphQL query in the index page including `videoThumbnail {relativePath}`.

Putting the video files in the static folder makes the links in the frontmatter unusable and deletes the video element through the Logical AND (or at least I don't know how to link them properly).

I've added `videoThumbnail {relativePath}` to the blogPost GraphQL query in `gatbsy-node.js`, without success.

Thank you in advance,
Georg